# How to use Stochastic integration by parts

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Hey I have problem with understanding this calculation (first, second and third equality)
[image]

In what way we use here integration by parts?

Comment: Probably used in integrating the thing that looks like $ue^{-u}$.